# How to display each error from JQuery post() function in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, post, laravel

I am stuck now. I have been trying all the answers in similar posts and i can't get it to work.
I got this form where a user can update his/her information. When either stopping typing or focusing out of the input text box, i send a request to the controller in order to update the info into the database. When sent to it, the controller validates that information, should it find an error, it returns the list of errors found by using the following piece of code:

```
if($validator->fails()){
   //return $validator->messages()->toJson(); This DOES NOT WORK :/
   $messages = $validator->Messages()->all();
   return Response::json($messages);// THIS DOES WORK!!! :)
}
```

And the type of json i get when there is one error is the following:

```
{"nombre_pila":["The field nombre pila is required."]}
```

And if two errors have been found:

```
{"nombre_pila":["The nombre pila must be at least 3 characters.","The nombre pila may only contain letters."]}
```

On the script side, i try to get those errors by using the following code:

```
$.post(url, editform, function(data,status){
  $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
  if(data=='success'){
    //alert('Dato '+currentId+' actualizado exitosamente! Status: ' + status);
    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
    $('#'+currentId).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success').addClass('has-feedback');
  }else{
    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
    $('#'+currentId).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    alert('Unknown process. Status: '+status+'. Data: '+data);
    $.each(data,function(i,error){
       console.log(error);
    });
    }
});
```

And i get the following error:

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

I can't find out how to display each of the errors found. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your errors array is inside object key `nombre_pila`, so instead of:

```
$.each(data,function(i,error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

do:

```
$.each(data.nombre_pila,function(i,error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But now i get this error: `TypeError: a is undefined`

Comment: The problem got solved, because in the Controller side, i fixed the return to: `return Response::json($messages);`. That did the trick mainly.